# In GAS, how can ‘instanceof’ be used for Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I would like to see if a variable is an instance of Spreadsheet or not.

Example,

```
function foo(hoge){
  let name;
  if (hoge isinstanceof SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet){
      name = hoge.getName()
  }else {
      name = hoge;
  }
}
```

but it seems I cannot do like this above. What should I change ‘SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet’ to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
function test101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(ss instanceof Object && ss.hasOwnProperty('toast')) {
     Logger.log('Then it is a spreadsheet');
  }
}
```

[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

[type of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: Thank you (I forgot to leave greetings..)